# Prevent coloring of org code block during html export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How can I tell emacs/org to not syntax color the outputted html when I'm exporting using org publish project feature. Alt-: Eval: (org-publish "blogproject1")

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports both                                                                                                                            
# bash comment                                                                                                                                          
pwd                                                                                                                                                     
#+END_SRC  

#+RESULTS:                                                                                                                                              
: /tmp
```

What I tried (in my init el )

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively nil)
```

[image]

In this case my motivation is: the coloring isn't compatible with a dark web theme.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `org-html-htmlize-output-type` user option to `nil` disable htmlize:

```el
(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type nil)
```

`C-h v org-html-htmlize-output-type` says

```
org-html-htmlize-output-type is a variable defined in `ox-html.el'.
Its value is `inline-css'

Documentation:
Output type to be used by htmlize when formatting code snippets.
Choices are `css' to export the CSS selectors only,`inline-css'
to export the CSS attribute values inline in the HTML or `nil' to
export plain text.  We use as default `inline-css', in order to
make the resulting HTML self-containing.

...
```