# How do I export code font-lock from Org to HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, font-lock, html

With the following `.emacs`
(on bleeding-edge GNU Emacs 30.0.50 and Org mode 9.6.1 in 2023)

```
;; Org -> LaTeX
(require 'ox-latex)
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "minted"))
(setq org-latex-listings 'minted)
(setq org-latex-pdf-process '("latexmk -shell-escape -f -pdf %f"))
;; Org -> HTML
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

I can see both the effect of `font-lock-fontify-buffer` in Emacs (left) and the result of `minted` in the LaTeX/PDF export (center), but no fontification following exporting to HTML.

[image: Org, LaTeX, and HTML]

How do I export font-lock from Org to HTML?

Related:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14438582/700648),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21005885/700648),
[3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/50791/28733),
[4](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/fontify-src-code-blocks.html),
...

Here is the
[sample](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_accumulators_framework)
source file.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usemintedstyle{default}

#+BEGIN_SRC c++
// Mean == (Sum / Count)
template<typename Sample>
struct mean_accumulator : accumulator_base
{
    typedef Sample result_type;
    mean_accumulator(dont_care) {}

    template<typename Args>
    result_type result(Args const &args) const
    {
        return sum(args[accumulator]) /
               count(args[accumulator]);
    }
};
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Make sure that `htmlize` is installed. Search the Org manual for `htmlize` and/or search the package list for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recall this worked at some point, but it no longer does, install `htmlize` (thanks to NickD for the pointer).

You will then duly get the requisite output.

[image: code fontified in HTML from Org]

If you've wiped out your `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory, a good way to not forget one package or another is to rely on
[package-install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10093312/700648).

Answer (score 0):

If that fails and you need a workaround, there's this code to turn an entire buffer into SVG (but only on X11 !).

```
;; useful trick from https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/idz35e/emacs_27_can_take_svg_screenshots_of_itself/
(defun screenshot-svg ()
  "Save a screenshot of the current frame as an SVG image.
Saves to a temp file and puts the filename in the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((filename (make-temp-file "Emacs" nil ".svg"))
     (data (x-export-frames nil 'svg)))
    (with-temp-file filename
      (insert data))
    (kill-new filename)
    (message filename)))
(define-key global-map [(super s)]  'screenshot-svg)
```

Comment: `x-export-frames` seems clever, but `x-anything` is too niche a solution. Forget about the Mac; it wouldn't even work on Linux flavors built with Qt; is that right?